# If we bound x on an interval, how can we bound |x|?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, absolute-value

We are given $a<x<b$, where $a$ and $b$ are constants. This means that $x$ belongs to the interval from $x=a$ to $x= b$ excluding $a$ and $b$.

> What is the interval that $|x|$ (the absolute value of $x$) belongs to?

This question continually bothered me when i was working in $ε-δ$ proofs. I've found an answer and I just want to make sure it's correct. 
We take 3 cases.

Case 1: $b> 0$ but $a <0$, case 2: both $a<0$ and $b<0$, case 3 : $a>0$ and $b>0$.

The answer in case one is $0≤|x|<\max(|b|,|a|)$. The answer in 2 would be $|b|<|x|<|a|$. And the answer in 3 is quite straightforward $a<|x|<b$. Is this correct ?

Comment: can you edit your question to make it more clear? I have no idea what you're asking. State clearly the problem, what have you tried to solve it, and any doubt you have regarding it.

Comment: I wrote a detailed explanation but this is my first question and im so new. The problem is that the site somehow only used a part of my question.  I don't know how to make it so the full question appears

Comment: @Ant here was my question  If a<x<b a, and b are constants. This means that x belongs to the interval from x=a to x= b excluding a and b. What is the interval that |x| (the absolute value of x) belongs to? This question continually bothered me when i was working in ε-δ proofs. I've found an answer and i just want to make sure its correct. We take 3 cases. Case: 1 b> 0 but a <0, case 2: both a<0 and b<0 , case 3 : a>0 b>0. The answer in case one is 0≤|x|<max(|b|,|a|). The answer in 2 would be |b|<|x|<|a|. And the answer in 3 is quite straightforward a<|x|<b. Is this correct ?

Comment: by the way, it appears it was a bug on the site actually. I just added random dollar signs and your text was visible again

Comment: @Ant It's not a bug. HTML tags start with a `<`. If the parser encounters a `<` and it is neither in code-mode nor in maths mode, it interprets it as the start of a HTML tag and what follows is not rendered (until something tells the parser that it shall no longer try to interpret things as a tag). Moral: if you see a garbled post, click "edit" and look for `<`s outside code or maths.

Comment: @DanielFischer Oh I see! Thank you for the explanation! :-) Weird that I've never noticed it before on the site

Answer (score 1):

As far as I can see it is indeed correct. Usually a little sketch is very useful in this cases to see what's going on